# MATLAB : access uigetdir's internal java methods

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-java

When using the standard dir dialog box from MATLAB uigetdir, double-clicking on a directory leads to the dialog box entering it and displaying its contents. To actually select it, you have to click on the "select directory" button.

What I would like is a way to add specific rules on what to do when double-clicking on a directory : basically, I would like to change/override the internal 'method/callback' associated to this action.

Problem is, said dialog box is NOT your usual Matlab figure - that I would know how to do easily (retrieve the handle, look at properties and edit/modify the corresponding callback). This looks like a raw Java object and I find no way to access this information from Matlab.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, instead of `uigetdir`:

```
fc = javax.swing.JFileChooser('/initial/path')
% then customise the dialog using Java methods, as you please!
fc.setFileSelectionMode(javax.swing.JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES)
chosenfile = fc.showOpenDialog([])
```

You could even add listener [callback](http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/matlab-callbacks-for-java-events/) to handle specific events if needed.